Installing MinionPro with FontPro on TexLive windows
I'm trying to install the MinionPro font on my texlive 2022 via the fontpro scripts. I have the otf files for minionpro, and texlive 2022 system on windows. The instructions given in the link are for miktex system. So I'm looking for resolutions to:

The proper way to carry out the installation on texlive.
To install LCDF typetools in cygwin as instructed.


Can you not just use LuaTeX with fontspec? LCDF typetools is included in TeX Live. And the link you posted is a 404.

Sorry, link is now fixed. As the readme file therein claims, "In contrast to other solutions, the supplied LaTeX packages provide extensive math support in the case of Minion and Myriad"

Yes, but if you can use LuaTeX you can use unicode-math and you don't need that kind of solution. (At least, I wouldn't think so. I'm assuming there's a good maths font for MinionPro.)

Nope, I had texlive installed before and not in cygwin

I'm wrong. I'm pretty sure that will install into wherever you tell it to install to. So you will need ./scripts/install /cygwin/c/... where ... points to TEXMFLOCAL under Windows. I guess you can get this at a Windows command line with kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL. Do that bit from cygwin, but point it at your Windows TeX Live. Then follow the updmap-sys instructions at the Windows command line. So the idea, as I understand it, is you're installing cygwin just to run makeall and install. That's a lot of overhead for relatively little. cont.

Actually, it isn't using make as far as I can tell. It's just a bash script.

'do that bit' -> 'run the install script' not the bit where you figure out TEXMFLOCAL.

Unfortunately, it looks like makeall command isn't working as it is supposed to. When I run ./scripts/makeall MinonPro in powershell, it just opens a pop-up asking me to select an application to open the file makeall.

You can't use powershell. You need to use bash under cygwin.

Thanks! I installed the fonts per your instruction. Now when I run updmap-sys enable Map=MinionPro.map, there is an error message "win32" is not exported by TexLive::TLUtils module

You're doing this at the Windows command line? That's what you want to do. What does updmap-sys --version or updmap-sys -version give? (I'm not sure which syntax is right for Windows -- or - but both work on Linux.)

Yes indeed, on command line. Your last command throws the same message as my previous comment.

I've asked in chat. I hope somebody on Windows will look. Only suggestion so far is that you're running updmap from cygwin rather than from powershell.

Put the fonts into the font directory of Window. And then use with lualatex:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{MinionPro}%
      [ Numbers            = {Monospaced,Lining},
        UprightFont        = *-Regular,
        ItalicFont         = *-It,
        BoldFont           = *-Bold, 
        BoldItalicFont     = *-BoldIt,
        UprightFeatures    = { SmallCapsFont = *-Regular },
        BoldFeatures       = { SmallCapsFont= *-Bold },
        ItalicFeatures     = { SmallCapsFont= *-It },
        BoldItalicFeatures = {  SmallCapsFont= *-BoldIt },
        Scale              = 1,
        Extension = .otf,
      ]

Maybe that you need an luaotfload-tool --update if it is not done automatically by lualatex.

This does not answer the question which is specifically about installing the fontpro support.
